# ArrayBuffer to String, String to ArrayBuffer Method(s)

Tags: javascript

This question has received answers in the past, but I would definitely say that it is still not answered.

There is almost documentation on ArrayBuffers in general, let alone on specific applications. I have been researching for days to no avail on this.

Essentially I need to try to convert an ArrayBuffer that I got from a file reader (here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) to a string, and then convert that string back to the same ArrayBuffer.

I have tried these methods for example

```
function ab2str(buf) {
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}

function str2ab(str) {
  var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length*2); // 2 bytes for each char
  var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
  for (var i=0, strLen=str.length; i<strLen; i++) {
    bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return b
```

I get the following error: "byte length of Uint16Array should be a multiple of 2"

I also tried the following

```
function StringToUint8Array(string) {
    var binary, binLen, buffer, chars, i, _i;
    binary = StringToBinary(string);
    binLen = binary.length;
    buffer = new ArrayBuffer(binLen);
    chars  = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= binLen ? _i < binLen : _i > binLen; i = 0 <= binLen ? ++_i : --_i) {
        chars[i] = String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(binary, i);
    }
    return chars;
}

function ArrayBufferToString(buffer) {
    return BinaryToString(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(new Uint8Array(buffer))));
}

function StringToArrayBuffer(string) {
    return StringToUint8Array(string).buffer;
}

function BinaryToString(binary) {
    var error;

    try {
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(binary));
    } catch (_error) {
        error = _error;
        if (error instanceof URIError) {
            return binary;
        } else {
            throw error;
        }
    }
}

function StringToBinary(string) {
    var chars, code, i, isUCS2, len, _i;

    len = string.length;
    chars = [];
    isUCS2 = false;
    for (i = _i = 0; 0 <= len ? _i < len : _i > len; i = 0 <= len ? ++_i : --_i) {
        code = String.prototype.charCodeAt.call(string, i);
        if (code > 255) {
            isUCS2 = true;
            chars = null;
            break;
        } else {
            chars.push(code);
        }
    }
    if (isUCS2 === true) {
        return unescape(encodeURIComponent(string));
    } else {
        return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.apply(chars));
    }
}
```

And received this error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

It seems that there are just no good methods for the following conversions: AB --> String || String -> AB

Comment: Can you show an example input you used? The first code is working fine for lorem ipsum.

Comment: I am uploading image file, using filereader to read as arraybuffer and then sending the contents to the ab2str

Comment: Maybe the file size is so large, that it causes more call stacks?

Comment: Also I should note that I am using PGP encryption on the strings with https://openpgpjs.org/, one thing to note that is I just tried a smaller image file and the methods "worked" (didn't cause any errors), but the image file that came out was still corrupted

Comment: What is interesting, is that if I do the exact same thing with a text file it comes out perfectly fine.

Comment: Also, if I use the original array buffer for download, the image is not corrupted. This means clearly the AB has been altered in someone during the String conversion - encrypted - decryption - and reformat to AB

Comment: Do you need the `ArrayBuffer` specifically anyway? Why not use `base64`?

Comment: I don't need it specifically, but it's the only way I have found so far of reading and downloading a file.

Comment: Basically my goal, is local client side file upload - encrypt with pgp - decrypt  with pgp - and then download the file contents

Comment: Try searching for `base64` and file inputs. It's super easy for uploads, drawing into `<img>` and downloads!

Comment: I can do the following already - read file as array buffer and then download array buffer contents as file

Comment: But I must also be able to read the file to perform the encryption

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111963/discussion-between-nick-lim-and-qwerty).

Comment: Hey, I finally got time to finish this. This PoC was more for my own curiosity, but still, [here](https://js.qry.me/pgp/secureimages.html) it is.

Answer (score 17):

Most browsers now have [`TextEncoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) and [`TextDecoder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder), and Node has [`util.TextEncoder`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_class_util_textencoder) and [`util.TextDecoder`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_class_util_textdecoder). This WHATWG standard provides straightforward methods to convert between byte arrays (which have a `buffer` attribute) and strings:

```js
const str = new TextDecoder().decode(byteArray);
const byteArray = new TextEncoder().encode(str);
const buffer = byteArray.buffer;
```

Comment: This does not construct an `ArrayBuffer` from a `String`.

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot to show how to access the buffer! Thanks for pointing that out, @bryc.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful edit, @webchitect!

Answer (score 7):

There is an asynchronous way using Blob and FileReader.

You can specify any valid encoding.

```
function arrayBufferToString( buffer, encoding, callback ) {
    var blob = new Blob([buffer],{type:'text/plain'});
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt){callback(evt.target.result);};
    reader.readAsText(blob, encoding);
}

function stringToArrayBuffer( string, encoding, callback ) {
    var blob = new Blob([string],{type:'text/plain;charset='+encoding});
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(evt){callback(evt.target.result);};
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
}


//example:
var buf = new Uint8Array([65,66,67]);
arrayBufferToString(buf, 'UTF-8', console.log.bind(console)); //"ABC"

stringToArrayBuffer('ABC', 'UTF-8', console.log.bind(console)); //[65,66,67]
```

Answer (score 3):

Complimenting the excellent answer by cuixping, here are the TypeScript versions of the conversion functions

```
const arrayBufferToString = (buffer: ArrayBuffer, encoding = 'UTF-8'): Promise<string> => {
  return new Promise<string>((resolve, reject) => {
    const blob = new Blob([buffer], { type: 'text/plain' });
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt) => {
      if (evt.target) {
        resolve(evt.target.result as string);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Could not convert array to string!'));
      }
    };
    reader.readAsText(blob, encoding);
  });
};

const stringToArrayBuffer = (text: string, encoding = 'UTF-8'): Promise<ArrayBuffer> => {
  return new Promise<ArrayBuffer>((resolve, reject) => {
    const blob = new Blob([text], { type: `text/plain;charset=${encoding}` });
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (evt) => {
      if (evt.target) {
        resolve(evt.target.result as ArrayBuffer);
      } else {
        reject(new Error('Could not convert string to array!'));
      }
    };
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
  });
};
```

Comment: You can initialize a Buffer more simply with `Buffer.from("string")`.