# How to Send PublicKeyCredential to server?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0, webauthn

**Preface**

I am new to cybersecurity. I've always been hesitant to implement an authentication system into personal projects because I was scared by the security implications (mainly passwords and authenticating a user). However, I am very excited about [WebAuthn](https://webauthn.guide) and [Apple's Passkeys](https://developer.apple.com/passkeys/) because this standard promises to be safer and *should* mean less responsibility for me! However, I have had a nightmare of a time trying to setup what I thought should be a simple demo project. There just isn't enough information or examples to work off of.

**Problem**

I have created a simple .NET 6 Web API project and a simple Angular project. Here is the flow so far:

1. User enters a username in Angular App to register with
2. Angular asks the server for a challenge. The server then uses the [Fido2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fido2.AspNet/) Nuget Package to generate the challenge
3. Angular receives the challenge and generates a new `PublicKeyCredential` using the challenge and calling `navigator.credentials.create(...);`

The above works perfectly. The next step *should* be to send the new `PublicKeyCredential` to the server so the server can store this credential for authentication later. The problem is that this `PublicKeyCredential` uses `ArrayBuffers` that cannot be serialized and sent to the server (at least not easily). Am I just doing this wrong? I just simply cannot find any solid and reliable way to get the `PublicKeyCredential` back to the server.

**What I have tried**

1. I have tried encoding the `ArrayBuffers` to strings *and* base64 strings as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37234333/arraybuffer-to-string-string-to-arraybuffer-methods) but this has not worked for me. When the credential gets to the server, I decode the `byte[]`, and attempt to call `_fido2.MakeNewCredentialAsync(...)` I get a weird error that says the "Attestation Object is invalid. Unhandled State. Was SimpleValue."
2. I tried the suggestion outlined in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67719572/publickeycredential-not-possible-to-serialize) but this package also assumes that the *server* will also be using this package. My server is an ASP.NET Web API, not a Node.js application so I didn't know how to use this library.
3. I have looked at the [Demo Library](https://github.com/passwordless-lib/fido2-net-lib/tree/master/Demo) provided by the Fido2 Nuget Package. The problem with this implementation is that the "Front End" and "Back End" are hosted together using a framework I'm not familiar with. Because of this, they can cut a few corners. They don't have to send the PublicKeyCredential 'back' to the server because it is already on the server! I'd like to have my Angular App and Server be separated (If possible)

**Conclusion**

If anyone has any examples of WebAuthn working in a very simple environment, I would love to take a look. Or if you have suggestions for me on my implementation that is also welcome!

Comment: Have you seen the demo site (https://github.com/passwordless-lib/fido2-net-lib/tree/master/Demo) associated with that FIDO2 library?

Comment: I have actually. I will update my question to include this. The problem with this implementation is that the "Front End" and "Back End" are hosted together using a framework I'm not familiar with. Because of this, they can cut a few corners. They _don't have_ to send the PublicKeyCredential 'back' to the server because it is already on the server! I'd like to have my Angular App and Server be separated (If possible)

Comment: You may find what you’re looking for in our project. We have a go API and a (p)react frontend: https://github.com/teamhanko/hanko

Comment: I'm not familiar with Angular or C#, but 'cutting corners' is not how the WebAuthn API works. PublicKeyCredential comes from the browser and MUST be sent back to the server one way or the other.

https://github.com/passwordless-lib/fido2-net-lib/tree/master/Demo/wwwroot/js has all the (plain) Javascript and the examples all use 'coerceToBase64Url' from helpers.js. 

Can you share _exactly_ what your code looks like? It almost sounds like you're trying to base64 the entire PublicKeyCredential object instead of only the ArrayBuffer proprties.

Comment: @Rafe I spent yesterday and this morning attempting to implement what this demo project has implemented. I guess I am just confused as to _WHY_ WebAuthn needs a `helper.js` file to "coerce" the PublicKeyCredential into any other type. Why can't I just send it to the server as it is given to me? Everything I'm doing and has been recommended to me feels very 'hacky'

Comment: The WebAuthn team is aware of the awkwardness, and there is an issue open to resolve it: https://github.com/w3c/webauthn/issues/1683

Comment: This makes me very sad 

Comment: Yeah, it's odd given the fact that it's fairly useless if you don't pass that data to the backend that there's not a baked in toJSON() function or something to do that serialization for us. I wouldn't call manually mapping a serialization-unfriendly object to make it serializable "hacky" though, just annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the answers to this question did ultimately help me get the PublicKeyCredential to the server (through much weeping and gnashing of teeth), it ultimately proved to be useless because of the problem outlined in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67186593/webauthn-issue-due-to-split-architecture) post. WebAuthn doesn't seem to be designed for 'split architecture'. Meaning that you must host your Web Application and your API on the same domain.

Because of this I am basically rethinking my entire approach and starting over trying to implement WebAuthn. Wish me luck!

Even as I type this answer I still have doubts. This just simply can't be the case can it? How are mobile applications supposed to implement WebAuthn if the FIDO2 exchange must happen on the same domain? Are mobile apps expected to load some kind of web view? Are all Web Applications expected to be hosted on the same domain as the Relying party? Or expected to load some sort of iframe? I am very confused, but determined to make WebAuthn work for me.

Comment: Any updates on this issue. I'm attemtping to update my website that uses svelte on the front and expressjs on the server. Did you get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I am hoping that more developers will start to implement WebAuthn and develop more elegant solutions to this problem now that Google officially supports Passkeys. You might also want to check out my demo project here for reference: https://github.com/Ranger-Rick/PasskeyDemo

Comment: " WebAuthn doesn't seem to be designed for 'split architecture'" When you wrote that, did you mean reverse proxy won't work? Or like serverless functions?

Answer (score 2):

`PublicKeyCredential.response`, after a `create` call, will be an [AuthenticatorAttestationResponse](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#iface-authenticatorattestationresponse). On that object are the functions `getPublicKey` and `getAuthenticatorData` (see [5.2.1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn-2/#sctn-public-key-easy)), which will get you the information that you need. But they do, indeed, both return ArrayBuffers.

You can base64-encode an ArrayBuffer, `a`, with something like `btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(a)))`.

Comment: I have implemented your suggestions and I am able to get the AuthenticatorAttestationResponse's properties to the server. In order to do this, I had to create my own DTO to manually encode all the ArrayBuffers and send them to the server. When I decode those Array buffers and try to create a new AuthenticatorAttestationResponse on the Server side, I get errors trying to make the credential on the Server side. The next step of the flow is to call `_fido2. MakeNewCredentialAsync()` but I continually get errors from this method, saying that the attestation object is not in the correct format.

Comment: @RangerRick are you able to share the serialized assertion and the corresponding server side model?